# Getting string from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with elements that are strings but are expressed as 'objects':

[image]

I want to access the string itself. This seems extremely simple but I can't seem to turn it into a string:

[image]

I also tried `vocab.iloc[0].astype(str)` and `.astype('|S')`  as suggested in another post but this still printed something similar to the first picture.

Edit: I just realized that the dataframe *titles* are the vocab words, and the entries are NaN.... The full dataframe looks something like
[image]. However I selected the answer that fits the assumption that dataframe entries are strings.

Comment: Can you post input data and code as text

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with python to know how to post a simple dataframe of strings, but it's a single-columned dataframe with string entries.

Comment: Can your print your Dataframe and post a sample, use `print(mydataframe.head())`

Comment: Try converting the entire dataframe to string: `vocab.astype(str)`, then run `vocab.iloc[0]`

Comment: @Abhi_J added to the end of the question.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen interesting suggestion, but unfortunately it returned the same thing :/

Comment: Your dataframe image shows the column is named `0`, but your first image shows the column is named `(crude,)`. Are you sure they're both from the same dataframe?

Comment: Did you run `vocab = vocab.astype(str)`? Only running `vocab.astype(str)` will not save the dataframe and will thus result in the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `iloc[n]` is used to index a row of a Dataframe not a single value, [refer this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)
2. From the image there are `NAN` values in the data, you can replace them using `.fillna()`
3. to get data type of an individual value in datafame try `df.iloc[0][0].__class__`
4. to get a single value eg first element use `df.iloc[0][0]`
5. to get all values(strings) as a list, use `df[<column name>].values` or in this case just `df.values` and then `.flatten()` to convert it from 2D list to a 1D list

sample:

```py
import pandas as pd #TODO
d1 = ['i', '11', '40', '42', '60' ,'50']
df = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df = df.fillna('')

print(df.iloc[0][0].__class__)

print(df.iloc[0][0])

print(df.values.flatten())
```

**Output:**

```
<class 'str'>

i

['i' '11' '40' '42' '60' '50']
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create a sample snippet comparable to your use case and extracted the desired element from the dataframe. See the comments in my snippet for further information and explanations:

```
import io

import pandas as pd


# define some lorem ipsum sample data to work with in this snippet
data_string = """
words
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
consetetur
sadipscing
elitr
sed
diam
"""

# convert string to file-like StringIO and load data into a dataframe
data = io.StringIO(data_string)
df = pd.read_csv(data)

# print the dataframe we will be working with
print(df)

# printing `.info()` will show us that the dataframe consists of objects (same as in your example)
print(df.info())

# let's have a look at the element at integer based index 0 (using `.iloc[0]`)
# this returns a named Series (named `words` here) with a single element
print(df.iloc[0])

# access the series value(s) by calling `.values`
print(df.iloc[0].values)

# as this is a single element Series, we could extract the element
element, = df.iloc[0].values
print(element)
```